# how to add product to cart in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Below is add to product code . But I am not getting where the values are storing . Kindly help to find out solution for this . I want to know logic behind this code

```
public function add($product_id, $qty = 1, $option = array(), $recurring_id = 0) {
    $this->data = array();

    $product['product_id'] = (int)$product_id;

    if ($option) {
        $product['option'] = $option;
    }

    if ($recurring_id) {
        $product['recurring_id'] = (int)$recurring_id;
    }

    $key = base64_encode(serialize($product));

    if ((int)$qty && ((int)$qty > 0)) {
        if (!isset($this->session->data['cart'][$key])) {
            $this->session->data['cart'][$key] = (int)$qty;
        } else {
            $this->session->data['cart'][$key] += (int)$qty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Values are store in session cart keys like `$key = base64_encode(serialize($product));` Also mention the opencart version

Comment: I m using opencart 2x

Comment: If you want to get information, you have to decode and unserialize. For ex. `unserialize(base64_decode($key));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product details with options are stored in `$key = base64_encode(serialize($product));`. Where `$this->session->data['cart'][$key]` contains the number of quantity added by the customer.

For more details check the `getProducts()` function on the same page. Where you can find

```
foreach ($this->session->data['cart'] as $key => $quantity) { 
  .... 
  $product = unserialize(base64_decode($key));
  ....
}
```

Comment: its displaying only last added product . how can i get all products id which there in cart

Comment: Find in the loop `$product_id = $product['product_id'];` It will give you a product id.

Comment: I  want to know how they are passing value . bcz I want to pass one more input filed value along with product ID. input filed is manual entry . can yo explain me that logic

Comment: If you want to add your own field then just add it in `add()` function of cart library. You will get that data when you call the `getProducts()` method.

Comment: include is not working in opencart . I want to include one file which is base mail.php.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain what exactly you want?

Comment: a:2:{s:10:"product_id";i:178;s:12:"recurring_id";i:0;} this is the key . I am not getting how it taking name and price ..

Comment: the product data is serialized and then base64 encoded, To get product data just do base64_decode and then unserialize it.

Comment: where it is serialized? what is that a:2 , s:10 ? I dint noticed any where like a:2 or s: like code

Comment: It is serialized in the function `add()` and unserialized in `getProducts()` function in the library file of `cart.php`.